# How to resolve the error Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use

Tags: php

[This is the link where i am getting error from server.php file.](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FTips%2F418814%2FSocket-Programming-in-PHP&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFtElsHM5xFprXLemc6MPLKDxzh5g)

I got an error `Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wheel/server.php on line 12
Could not bind to socket Address already in use

Comment: Check what is using the port you want to use, end it. Or choose a different port.

Comment: If i change the port number also i am getting same error.

Comment: What port are you using? Are you sure it's available and not in use by any other service?

Comment: i used 2428 port. but also i tried many port no.

Comment: Well, post your code, without it nobody can help you.

Answer (score 2):

That error means there's something already listening on that port you're trying to listen on.

To find the culprit, use:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

Then, after you made **very** sure you want to kill it, kill it, with either

```
kill $PID
```

or, if that doesn't work, use the crowbar:

```
kill -9 $PID
```

(replace $PID with the process id you want to kill)

some further information:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/